# git push to current branch not working after pulling a previous commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

After pulling an older commit, when I commit and push the changes, the changes are not taking place and the only output I get is 
`Everything is upto date`.

No other changes takes place anywhere. The commits just won't work.

I tried changing the current branch and even the origin a few times, nothing happens. Same output.

Comment: did you check if your remote branch is where you are looking right now?

Comment: @user404 yes, i tripple checked.

Comment: Can you show our the output of gir status and git push?

Comment: @tymtam the output is `Everything up-to-date`. And nothing else. When i check the commit id, it's different on my local machine but that id does not show up on BitBucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if you're looking at different branches.

[image]

Comment: i am on the same branch i wish to push.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes that can happen
1:Maybe you're working on different branch
2:first saveAll files then run commands
 First add then commit then push

Comment: I did, but same result. I tried changing the branch to a different one. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your remote origin

```
git remote show origin
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have not yet found out why this was happening, I found out somewhat of an alternative to commit the changes.

What I did was simply,

- Keep a backup of the current changes I want to commit and push to BitBucket
- Clone the project again where I last left off
- Making the changes in the codes
- And then commit and push

I don't know why this worked for me. Not sure why I was facing the problem in the first place.